# How to position Bootstrap's dropdown menu to the right of a floating right toggle element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Ok, title should be self explanatory. And yes, I can see on bootstrap docs that they've added the class `dropdown-menu-right` so that it would work on a situation similar to mine.

It kinda works on the link below. Dropdowns are to the right of toggle element.

(Dropdowns are on the second tab)

http://plnkr.co/edit/gkbEkv86dTTvWZCAeUp0?p=preview

However, what I'm actually trying to do is to have the toggle element float to the right (to the end of the heading), like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0qMNLgabRrfAC2Evw1ri?p=preview

But as you can see, the dropdowns are still presented at the same place as before. It ignores the fact that the toggle element now is to the right.

I'm using Bootstrap along with Angular UI directives. However, I'm pretty certain that the problem is CSS relative.

Once I actually found out that this is the problem, what I've tried is to set relative to elements and reposition the dropdown with `right: 0` but it didn't work.

Does anybody know  how can I have the toggle element of a dropdown floating to the right and then show the dropdown menu to consider the float?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.panel-heading > .dropdown {
   position: static;
}
```

...applied to your second plunkr will do the trick.

As a side note, you shouldn't apply `position:relative` inline to `.panel-heading`s. You should do it only once, via `CSS`. If you want to make sure you don't affect the rest of the project, prefix your selector with a specific id. In your case, `#right-box` seems fit for the job:

```css
#right-box .panel-heading { position: relative; }
```

Comment: I don't understand how `static` made it work but yeah, its working, thanks. Also, for some reason, it only works if `panel-heading` has `position: relative`. This was actually leftover from my attempts to make this work. Since I need it, I'll use as you suggested with the Id of the container as a prefix.

Comment: `position:static` means *"not positioned"* and is the default value of any `HTML` element's `position`. What you're doing by overriding (canceling) the `position:relative` on `.dropdown` (from Bootstrap) is to make your `.dropdown-menu` position itself relative to its next `position`ed parent (not `static`). In order to work properly, that parent needs to be `.panel-heading`.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Thanks.